# void cross divisor in c++?

Tags: vectors

I have been assigned the task of completing a program but I am not able to understand what question is saying. I don't want solution but I just only want to understand the meaning. Here is the question.

**void Cross Divisors (vector A, vector B, vector C)
This function should save in C all the possible divisions between the elements of A and the elements of B, without adding repeating elements. Use the above functions to simulate the result known in algebra as the theorem of the rational roots.**

Can anyone make me understand the meaning of it?

Comment: It means looking at the numbers $a_1/b_1,a_1/b_2,a_1/b_3,a_2/b_1,...,a_3/b_3$ (OR it could be b/a, I'm not sure what is intended by the phrasing "divisions between elements", but the concept is the same) without having repeated numbers. For example, if $A=(1,2,3)$ and $B=(2,5,4)$, then $a_1/b_1 = a_2/b_3 = 0.5$, so you wouldn't want to repeat this number twice.

Comment: Is this about the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem ?

Comment: Is this a programming question (C++ in the title) or a mathematical question?

Comment: @Martin It is the assignment in c++

Comment: @AmejiB. That means I have to store all combination divisions of (a)i / (b)i in vector c without repeating.

Comment: @Ajaykumarsoni yes, that should be what is intended. That is the same process as in the rational root theorem where vwctor A would be the divisors of the constant coefficient and B would be the divisors of the leading coefficient

Comment: For the C++ side, `std::set<double>` will be useful to avoid repeats.

Comment: @AmejiB.  Thank's I got it !